# Accessing a runtime assigned Object from another component?

Tags: unity-game-engine, runtime, nullreferenceexception, assign, unity-components

As it stands I can't seem to make sense of the events in my program. I have two components. One called `EnemyMeleeSwitching` and one called `EnemyAI`.

`EnemyMeleeSwitching`, who's script is contained in the same parent level as `EnemyAI` at runtime selects a random `Weapon`(object) from a list and assigns the `enemyWeapon` object variable as that `Weapon`.

Now I am under the impression that accessing the `EnemyMeleeSwitching` component and further the `Weapon` component from my `EnemyAI` script should allow me to then access `enemyWeapon` however I am getting a `NullReferenceException`.

Does this have something to do with execution order? Is my `EnemyAI` script trying to access `enemyWeapon` before it's been assigned?

`EnemyMeleeSwitching` Code below:

```
public class EnemyWeaponSwitching : MonoBehaviour 
{
    public Weapon enemyWeapon;
    public Weapon weapon01;
    public Weapon weapon02;

    private List<Weapon> weapons = new List<Weapon>();

    void Start()
    {
        weapons.Add(weapon01);
        weapons.Add(weapon02);

        enemyWeapon = weapons[Random.Range(0, weapons.Count)];

        foreach (Weapon weapon in weapons)
        {
            weapon.SetActive(false);
        }

        enemyWeapon.SetActive(true);
    }
}
```

`EnemyAI` Code call below:

```
weapon = (Weapon)gameObject.GetComponent<EnemyWeaponSwitching>().enemyWeapon;
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As a follow up to my question I managed to solve this problem by moving the code from `Start()` to a new function which I called after establishing a reference to `EnemyWeaponSwitching`. This assigned the required object variable before I then called it in my `EnemyAI` code.

New code below:

(`EnemyAI`)

```
weaponSwitching = gameObject.GetComponentInChildren<EnemyWeaponSwitching>();
        weaponSwitching.GenerateWeapon();

        attackRange = weaponSwitching.enemyWeapon.maxAttackRange;
```

(`EnemyWeaponSwitching`)

```
public void GenerateWeapon()
{
    weapons.Add(weapon01);
    weapons.Add(weapon02);

    enemyWeapon = weapons[Random.Range(0, weapons.Count)];

    foreach (Weapon weapon in weapons)
    {
        weapon.SetActive(false);
    }

    enemyWeapon.SetActive(true);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Yes, it is possible that EnemyAI is accessing enemyWeapon before it is assigned. 1. Try to move your code from EnemyWeaponSwitching Start() method in Awake() method. 
Or 
2. Try to change the execution order or your scripts.

Comment: Hi there, yes I figured this out but forgot to update my answer. Thanks though! Upvoted.